# Undefined reference to main error when I run a program in WSL

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, undefined-reference

I am very new to programming and right now I am mostly at the stage where I copy/paste stuff to understand. I am not even sure I will understand the answers or if my question is worth asking but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else so here I came.

I wrote a "Hello World!" program in C;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The file name is hello.c and when I ran it in CodeBlocks it worked just fine

Afterwards I opened Ubuntu terminal (WSL) and typed the following

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

However it gives me the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried using -Wall and -Werror but they didn't work.

What the problem might be and how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does CodeBlocks print out the commands its running? You may want to take a look at those, and look up any flags you don't know.

Comment: Also, are you SURE that the source file you are compiling is saved, and indeed does have the main function inside of it?

Comment: In the terminal where you run `gcc`, try e.g. `cat hello.c` to see the actual source you're building. Is it the one you expect?

Comment: I am sure the file is running perfectly in codeblocks and there is no typing mistakes and the source file is saved

Comment: I tried cat hello.c now, but it doesn't return anything

Comment: That means you have an *empty* file named `hello.c` and are trying to build it. Which of course would lead to such an error you describe. You simple aren't in the correct location.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really have been searching a lot and couldn't find anything just because I wasn't at the right location...It works now that I tried to run it with the right location